# Icons priority on action bar

Tags: android, resources

If several icons are shown on an action bar with `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and there is no enough space for all icons, how Android decides, what icon to show? Is it possible to set relative icons importance?

Answer (score 8):

You should use `android:orderInCategory`, from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) :

> Integer. The order of "importance" of the item, within a group.

Comment: Thanks. How to set priority: does 0 mean high or low priority?

Comment: AFAIK, a higher integer represents higher priority.

Comment: Is there some reference for this. I didn't find anything for now.

Comment: added the link to the documentation.

Comment: This page doesn't describe, how to set priority. I need some confirmation, that a higher integer represents higher priority.

Comment: You can test this in something like 20 seconds. And no, higher integer isn't highest priority, it's the other way around. 1 (or perhaps 0) is the highest priority.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu I've got a similar problem and can't find a solution.  If you have time can you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475316/icons-priority-on-action-bar-keeping-order-of-items