# Icon's priority on action bar (keeping order of items)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to control which action bar items get shown if there is limited space, and have tried the solution in this question and answer: [Icons priority on action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916777/icons-priority-on-action-bar)

Everything works fine other than I want to keep the order of the icons in a manner which is different to the priority, whereas the solution above causes the items to be reordered.  Is there any way to set a priority for item display, without altering the order that items appear in the actionbar?

I've tried altering the order of the items in the xml, and this has no impact on the order of items as rendered (without the orderInCategory, changing the order in the file does result in a change in the order of items as rendered).

I'm developing against ICS.

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:title="@string/action_edit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_undo"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
        android:title="@string/action_undo"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="@string/action_delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        />

    <!-- I want this item to be on the right, 
    but shown in preference to any other items; 
    setting it's orderInCategory to 0 ensures that it 
    is shown in preference to other items, 
    but always places it on the left -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_addnew"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/action_addnew"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        />
</menu>
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @GCH Please review my answer

Answer (score 4):

The items are placed from **Right to Left** order so by rearranging the items, it can help

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_addnew"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:title="@string/action_addnew"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    />
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:title="@string/action_edit"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_undo"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
        android:title="@string/action_undo"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
    />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="@string/action_delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
    />
</menu>
```

Comment: I've tried this (I'll edit the question) and it seems to make no difference - the value in orderInCategory seems to override the order that items appear in the file.  For the avoidance of doubt, using xml like in the question and xml like in your answer produce the same results.

Comment: remove the android:orderInCategory="" property and then try

Comment: If you want some items to appear in overflow mode, group them in <menu> tag

Comment: I have and have edited the question - I can alter the order without orderInCategory, but need order in category to ensure that I can control the priority of items shown if there is not enough space to show all items.  In this case, I always want the add new button to be shown, but I want it on the right.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the <menu> tag comment, can you clarify?

Comment: Hmm.  menu isn't a valid tag within menu - I've just tried <group> instead and played with the orderInPriority in this, but to no avail.  Thank you for your help - I'll keep trying things

Answer (score 1):

What i got from reading your question is you want to display action_addnew should appear in the right & it should always appear to everyone. 
Try this one

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_edit"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:title="@string/action_edit"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_undo"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
            android:title="@string/action_undo"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_delete"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            android:title="@string/action_delete"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_addnew"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:title="@string/action_addnew"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            />
    </menu>
```

Comment: This will almost certainly work in this specific case, where I have one icon which will almost certainly fit.  The android documentation states for "always" that "Always place this item in the Action Bar. Avoid using this unless it's critical that the item always appear in the action bar. Setting multiple items to always appear as action items can result in them overlapping with other UI in the action bar.".  In this case, I don't mind if the button ends up on the overflow menu if there isn't space but, if it does show, I'd like to be able to control the location to which it renders.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, once I know how to do this, I'll specify an order to display the other items, which won't necessarily be the order of priority in which they should be shown on the bar/hidden on the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

From Left to Right give first item

```
android:orderInCategory="0"
```

and second item

```
android:orderInCategory="1"
```

so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:orderInCategory
```

This filed works from Right to Left so you need to right your code according to keep that in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What should I do in order to get the behaviour I desire?